# How to iterate in nested children with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple `Form` component that loops through its children and searches for any children with name of "`FormField`", then attaches event handlers to those children.

```
export default class Form extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.fields = {}
  }
  handleFieldChange(name, value) {
    const newFields = {...this.fields}
    newFields[name] = value;

    this.props.onChange(newFields)
  }
  render() {
    this.children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
      if (child.type.name == 'FormField') {
        this.fields[child.props.name] = child.props.data;
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          onChange: this.handleFieldChange.bind(this, child.props.name)
        })
      }
      return child
    })
    return (
      <div className="form">{this.children}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

---

This enables me to do this:

```
<Form onChange={this.handleFormChange.bind(this)}>
  <FormField label="Title" name="title" data={item.title} validators={[required]}>
    <TextInput placeholder="Example"></TextInput>
  </FormField>
</Form>
```

But not this (note the div):

```
<Form onChange={this.handleFormChange.bind(this)}>
  <div>
    <FormField label="Title" name="title" data={item.title} validators={[required]}>
      <TextInput placeholder="Example"></TextInput>
    </FormField>
  </div>
</Form>
```

This gives me an error in the `FormField` component that

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onChange is not a function

I'd like to be able to put divs (and possibly nested divs, etc) inside my `Form` component and still have it find the `FormField` components, so that I can layout my form and inputs with css.

How can I do that?

Edit: I've tried recursively iterating, but I get a stack overflow.

```
// FIXME: Won't work because of recursion error
function traverseChildren(children, self) {
  return React.Children.map(self.props.children, (child, index) => {
    if (child.type.name == 'FormField') {
      self.fields[child.props.name] = child.props.data;
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        onChange: self.handleFieldChange.bind(self, child.props.name)
      })
    } else {
      if (child.props.children) {
        return traverseChildren(child.props.children, self)
      }
      return child
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: It feels a bit 'wrong'. Why do you need to iterate over created `FormFields`. You could give your `onChange` method as a prop to your any components and at the end of your `FormField`'s `onChange` method you can trigger `this.props.onChange` to bind with higher hierarchy.

Comment: What are you trying to say? A little bit hard to understand. But anyway, why does it feel wrong? I need to bind the onchange event to FormFields only, and I need them to be nested because of layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a good case for having a look at react's [`context`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

In your case the parent could put a `onChange` method onto it's context which the children will be able to call.

A relatively short and hopefully useful example of how this could be approached can be found [here](https://github.com/chenglou/react-radio-group/blob/74a6969acbfae03617979ae47a6df0293b24ca77/index.jsx)

`RadioGroup` establishes a context which `Radio` is able to use. No matter how deep down in the dom the `Radio` is placed.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation, but I'm unsure how I should write it in ES6. This definitely seems like the answer though.

Comment: Here's a gist describing how to use context with es6 classes and es7 class properties: https://gist.github.com/danielberndt/9213f2995970d58564a372996e5f53d8

Comment: What's "myForm" in this example?

Comment: That's the name of your context. You can freely choose it, but you need to be somewhat careful to avoid name clashes with libraries that use contexts as well.

Comment: Ah so "formData" would be a good name? I see. Any way of iterating the children so I can add the name of the fields to the state? On mount probably.

Comment: perfectly fine name, yes :). Regarding your second point have a look [here](https://github.com/danielberndt/react-reform/blob/master/src/core/wrap-input.js#L59-L63). I actually wrote a basic [framework for form-handling](https://github.com/danielberndt/react-reform). So there might be some useful stuff for you to look at in the sources :)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, I'm fairly new to react and your project is a little bit advanced. But I could just have each formfield call a method on the Form when created, and then the form just adds that field to its state?

Comment: Yes, the code certainly isn't optimised for legibility. But yeah, the idea is that the `Form` puts a `register` and `unregister` method on its context and each `Form`-aware component calls them when mounting/unmounting.

Comment: Would like to inform you that it's working, but what's the risk of react updating and breaking the entire thing? Thanks!

Comment: First off, a lot of important react libraries (react-redux, react-router, etc) rely on `context`. So it's a fairly sage bet, especially since react is doing a very good job at deprecating responsibly. (i.e upgrading to the next major version won't break your code, it will just issue warnings if your code is going to break one major release after that)
Nonetheless I would recommend passing context handling into "Higher Order Components". Such that changes on how context works won't have too big an impact on your code base.

Answer (score -1):

When you add a new div, you need to get your form fields from `this.props.children.children`

To make it work for FormFields that are at any depth, you you have to recursively traverse children cloning the nodes you're interested in to put into the new children array you will create

Comment: that will work for the code snippets posted in the question, but not if `<FormField>` components are nested more than one level deep.  "put divs inside my `Form`" is ambiguous, and nested `<div>`s might end up being what the OP wants.

Comment: You mean how to make it work for both cases? Search recursively for FormField and clone those objects.

Comment: @DanO You're spot on.